# Include file inside target definition

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a group of files which contains environment variables to be defined according to the environment they represent. My Makefile will be run using an input parameter named `env`, and this will set the file that will be used.

I know I can load the according file by just doing:

```
include ./envs/$(env)
.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES:
```

But I would like to first check that the passed parameter is valid, and if not prompt an error message saying what happens. For this, I tried doing:

```
ENVS := dev prod local

.PHONY: all set_env use_env

all: set_env use_env

.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES:

set_env:
    ifeq ($(filter $(env),$(ENVS)),)
        $(error Invalid value por "env" argument: $(env). Accepted values: $(ENVS))
    endif
    include ./envs/$(env)
    @ echo Environment variables loaded

use_env:
    @ echo $(MY_VAR)
```

but I keep geting the following error `Makefile:14: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.`. Bash commands use tabs for indentation and the rest spaces (for better visualization).

Is it possible to use `include` inside a target instead of in the root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Makefiles are parsed in two completely distinct steps.  First all makefiles, included files, etc. are parsed and an internal graph of the prerequisite relationship is created in memory.  Second the graph is walked and recipes are invoked when they are needed.  I don't even know what it would mean to delay including a makefile until a recipe is run.

But I don't understand why you want to put this into a rule.  If you always want the file included, and you just want to check it first, why not just do the things you're doing in `set_env` (except the `echo` obviously), but at the global level and NOT in a target recipe?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it made things more clear for me. You are completely right, this error is because I just started working with Makefile's today. At first, I tried doing what you suggest: running this step at the start of the file no matter what. However, I was getting errors which I didn't know what they meant. Your "obvious" comment gave me the hint: I was running an `echo` command outside the target, which I guess is not supported. I moved everything but the echo outside the target and it's now working perfectly. Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Makefiles consist of two different languages in the same file.  There's the language make understands, which is documented in the make manual.  And there are shell commands, that make will pass to the shell to run.  Shell commands are part of a recipe, and are indented by TAB characters.  make operations are not part of a recipe, and are not indented by TAB characters.  Of course there are many special cases, but that's the basics.